# How to find all item files in Minecraft Bedrock Edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I can't seem to find any of the Minecraft Bedrock Edition item files.  Specifically, I am looking for the bow.  I need it to create a behavior pack with it.  The template behavior pack contains all food/farming items, but no others. Hours of looking up how to find them lead me nowhere.  I watched a few tutorials on how to get the bedrock game files, and in all of them there was a "vanilla" file in the com.mojang folder.  I checked every sub-folder in com.mojang and didn't find them either.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you’re thinking that addons for bedrock work like mods in java. They don’t. Most of the things you see in Minecraft are not possible in the JSON/JavaScript Bedrock API. You can’t make a bow, sorry. The items in bedrock are limited to the following behaviors: blocks, seeds, ordinary items, foods, potions, or a combo of food and potions (like a gapple), and maybe some other random thing I forgot.